# Symfony6 how to correctly configure sendmail to send emails from localhost

Tags: php, symfony, email

Basically on my home Ubuntu machine I want to be able to send emails in my symfony applications from localhost. I have installed sendmail with its basic configuration. I can send an email using the command line: `sendmail -v` command. The email is received. I can even use the PHP function to send the email:

```
$to = "receiver@mail.com";
$subject = "My subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: sender@mail.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers
```

The email is received.

However, using the symfony mail functionality I am not getting the emails and I am not receiving any errors either.

This is my sendmail configuration in php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; https://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; https://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; https://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; https://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

This is my symfony php code:

```
public function resetPassword(User $user, ResetPasswordToken $resetToken): void
{

    $to = "receiver@mail.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "Hello world!";
    $headers = "From: sender@mail.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers); // <----- THIS IS WORKING!!!


    $subject = 'My subject';

    $email = (new TemplatedEmail());
    $email->from(new Address('sender@mail.com'));
    $email->to('receiver@mail.com');
    $email->subject($subject);
    $email->htmlTemplate('shop/email/reset_password.html.twig');
    $email->context([
        'resetToken' => $resetToken
    ]);

    try {
        $this->mailer->send($email); // <----- THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!
    } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        dd($e->getCode());
    }
}
```

In my .env file I have tried multiple different configurations including:

```
###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=smtp://localhost
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=sendmail://default
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> symfony/mailer ###
MAILER_DSN=native://default
###< symfony/mailer ###
```

None of them worked. Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: you get any exceptions?

Comment: Sounds lie a good time to break out the debugger and see where it's going

Answer (score 2):

So appareantly everything was fine. The problem was that if you install symfony with their installer using the `--webapp` option, the queue messenger is installed: https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html and all my emails where in queue. Removing the messenger fixed my problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

debug the `$this->mailer` e.g. first with `dd()` and if it doesnt help... do actually proper debug.

as well, keep in mind that sometimes clearing cache can help

`php bin/console cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my `.env.local` const to use one of the docker containers:

1. `MAILER_DSN=smtp://mailhog:1025`
2. `MAILER_DSN=smtp://mailer:1025`

Where `mailhog` or `mailer` is the name of docker container in docker-compose.yml:

```
    mailer:
        image: schickling/mailcatcher
        container_name: app-mailer
        ports:
            - "1080:1080" # web
            - "1025:1025" # smtp

    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
        container_name: app-mailhog
        ports:
            - "8025:8025"
```